# Pass value of input to v-model

Tags: laravel, vue.js, v-model

how to pass automatticly the value of the input into the v-model ? 
Thank you :)

Code :

```
  <input   value="{{$in->id}}" v-model="upload.id" >
```

i tried to do in my script :

```
 upload: {
        bank:'',
        id:{{$in->id}},
        cash:''
  },
```

and in my view :

```
  <a   value="" v-model="upload.id" ></a>
```

Comment: @Badgy, it's Vue.js, as per the tags.

Comment: @Adam yes i know but i doubt there is no cleaner solution to even get the data etc. he managed to make it look like a mess with only 3 lines of code

Answer (score 2):

You can't do it that way as `v-model` overrides the `value` attribute on the input element. So probably the best option would be to add this straight to your `script` tag.

```
<script type="text/javascript>
new Vue({
  data: {
    upload {
      id: {{$in->id}}
    }
  }
});
</script>
```

Or, if you are initiating VueJS within it's own javascript file, instead of inline you could set it as a property on the window. For example, in your `<head>` you can do the following:

```
<head>
  ...
  <script type="text/javascript">
    window.sharedData = window.sharedData || {};
    window.sharedData.uploadId = {{$in->id}};
  </script>
  ...
</head>
```

This means in your javascript file you could then do the following:

```
data: {
  upload: {
    in: window.sharedData.uploadId
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, i tried to do the same but my vuejs isnt not working, please check my eddited post to see what i did

Comment: {{$in->id}} is undefined, I'm using a loop before,@foreach($coinbank as $in)